# Replace element in Coq list

Tags: computer-science, coq, proof-general

I am writing Coq code that needs to modify lists, particularly by accessing an index `i`, applying a function to that element, and replacing it back. I know I can acces the elemenent of a list by using `nth` as defined in [`Coq.Lists.List`](https://coq.github.io/doc/v8.9/stdlib/Coq.Lists.List.html). Then, I could apply the function to this element, but what would be the best way to insert the element back into the original list using the `Coq.Lists.List` library?

I currently have the following code:

```coq
Definition bv (n : nat) := list bool. 
Definition get_bv {n : nat} (i : nat) (v : bv n) := nth i v false.
Notation " v [ i ]" := (get_bv i v) (at level 0).
```

So given the function that I want to apply `f : bool -> bool`, I could do `f(v[i])`, but I'm not sure how to replace it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to apply the same function to every element of a list,
you can use `map`. Instead, if you want to only replace one
single element of a list, you may need to write your own replace function. For example:

```coq
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Fixpoint replace {A : Type} (l : list A)  (i : nat) (v : A) := 
  match l with 
  | [] => []
  | a :: l1 => match i with 
               |    0 => v :: l1 
               | S i1 => a :: replace l1 i1 v 
               end 
  end.

Compute replace [true; false; true] 2 false.
```

Answer (score 1):

Coq uses a functional programming paradigm, so you cannot "replace" an element as you would in an imperative programming language. But you can create a new list with the element at position `i` being `f (v[i])` instead of the (old) `v[i]`, all the other elements being the same as in the original list.

Note that the mathcomp `seq.v` library already provides a `set_nth` function that does exactly that.